Probability of getting the same pairings in 2 rounds of games from 2 teams of 4
If you’ve got 2 teams of 4 people and they’re going to play each other in pairs in 2 rounds, what are the chances the pairings are the same both times?
Eg
If team 1 has members A,B,C & D
Team 2 has member E,F,G,&H
Team 1 randomly picks out of a hat which member of team 2 they will play in round 1 (so everyone plays both rounds)
They then put all the names back in the hat and draw again.
What are the chances everyone gets the same person in round 2?
I had it as (1/4 x 1/4) x (1/3 x 1/3) x (1/2 x 1/2) x (1 x 1) =1/576
Which seems very low? Is that correct?

There are $4!=24$ possible permutations, and only one which matches the first round, so $\frac 1{24}$.  Your calculation gives the probability that a particular match up occurs twice in a row, but there are $24$ possible match ups.

It is not clear to me whether by pairings you mean four  singles matches per round, or two doubles matches per round. Pl. clarify.

Your $1/576$ is the probability of a particular arrangement occurring twice, but there are $24$ possible arrangements and so your approach should have $24/576 = 1/24$.

Thank you all! I understand, I knew 1/576 couldn’t be correct, just couldn’t figure out where I was going wrong  makes sense!
